# Android prevent working on background

Tags: android, service

I wrote a service which is registering a Smsreciever, and always work on background.
Also, i wanna prevent my main activity to working on background while not using the program. Generally it is working but sometimes my activity starting and running at background after recieved sms, it causes battery consumption, how can i prevent that

```
public void onCreate()
{
    ...

    startService(new Intent(this,ServiceCommunicator.class));

    ...
}               

 public void onBackPressed() {

    super.onBackPressed();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()) ;

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

some notes about what you are doing:

1. it is not advised to kill your process . just let the service continue . when you call "startService" it should continue even after the activity was closed.
2. background service can , by definition, die whenever the system thinks it needs memory . if you don't want to miss sms events , make your service run on the foreground .
3. the more cpu and battery your service uses , the more chance the os will decide to kill it . services should be as lite as possible , and if they do a lot of work for a long time , they should be in the foreground .
4. if your activity uses a lot of CPU , your service might also be closed when closing the app , since they both belong to the same process. you can change the process of the service via the manifest.

Comment: thanks, i changed in this way. But i wonder, when i kill my process it closes everything and not using battery. Is it same when i finished my all activities?

Comment: when you kill your process it includes everything of your app , including the services (unless you've set them to belong to a different process) . however , in order to know why your app uses a lot of cpu/battery , we need to see some code ... when you finish the activities , they are in a stopped state . they do not use CPU unless you've done something weird in the code.